# call aspect service method before Restful Api method called

Tags: java, spring, aop

How is it possible to make sure that aspect service method (i.e using annotation @before and expression) is called before the the rest APi method is called.

for example

```
public class Student {
  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Path("/{studentId}")
  public JSONWithPadding getStudentDetails(@QueryParam("callback") String callback,
    @PathParam("studentId") String studentId,
    @Context javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request) {

  }

}


class SomethingAspect {

  @Before("execution(*get*())")
  public void doSomethingAdvice(){
    System.Out.prinltln("do something");
  }
```

I want `doSomethingAdvice()` aspect to called before `getStudentDetails()` but since `Student` class is not getting through Spring bean how it would called the aspect.

Comment: How do you configure AOP? Which library do you use? How?

Comment: I see you are usign JAX-RS for the RestAPI. Are you using it alone or with it's Spring integration?

Comment: @LutzHorn i am usual AOP .Not using spring+rest api.Take it as i am already having an application using restful api and now wanna introduce AOP to support the above mention functionality.Is there a way to say that when this rest call happen getStudentDetails() call doSomethingAdvice But i think problem is as im not initiating the  bean Student through spring so how does it know how to call SomethingAspect()

Comment: @geoand  i am usual AOP .Not using spring+rest api.Take it as i am already having an application using restful api and now wanna introduce AOP to support the above mention functionality.Is there a way to say that when this rest call happen getStudentDetails() call doSomethingAdvice But i think problem is as im not initiating the bean Student through spring so how does it know how to call SomethingAspect()

Comment: @jeanlorey You are correct! In order for Spring AOP to be applied to a bean, that bean needs to be managed by Spring. There for in your case you can't use AOP

Comment: @geoand thanks so could you tell me how i can achieve this , might some other alternatives. THanks ..

Comment: @jeanlorey Which implementation of JaxRS are you using? Jersey, RestEasy or something else?

Comment: @geoand Im using jersey

Comment: @jeanlorey If you are using Jersey 1.x, check out this blog post http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/